# Dependancy update in Spark while loading csv

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

While trying to load csv file in community databricks I'm getting this error:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: 
>   Failed to fetch https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thomaspernet/data_csv_r/master/data/adult.csv during dependency update.

Actually I tried to load this csv file first but found that that path doesn't exists. So I changed the path to another csv file. However it's showing the same error for that as well.

I could not able to read any csv files now. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: It would be better if you add some code your'e using to get more help

Answer (score 1):

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thomaspernet/data_csv_r/master/data/adult.csv` resolves to `404: Not Found`.

What was the path to the new csv file? Are you sure it also isn't returning a `404` status?

It looks like the repo `data_csv_r` has been deleted, hidden or removed from user `thomaspernet` [GitHub account](https://github.com/thomaspernet).

Answer (score 1):

As @fnet mentioned, the link is no longer responsive. The following links may give you what you seek:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guru99-edu/R-Programming/master/adult.csv

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guru99-edu/R-Programming/master/adult_data.csv